# Google Api for creating contact with php code

Tags: php, google-api-client, google-people-api

I have created one function in which i am getting error related to Scope

Below is the code:

```
 $client = getClient();
 $client->addScope(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS);
 $service = new Google_Service_PeopleService($client);


 $person = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Person();
 $email = new Google_Service_PeopleService_EmailAddress();
 $email->setValue('test@test.com');
 $person->setEmailAddresses($email);
 $name = new Google_Service_PeopleService_Name();
 $name->setDisplayName('User de Test');
 $person->setNames($name);
 $phoneNumber = new Google_Service_People_PhoneNumber();
 $phoneNumber->setType('Home');
 $person->setPhoneNumbers($phoneNumber);
 $exe = $service->people->createContact($person);
 print_r($exe);*
```

Getting Error As Below:

> message: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.    errors: [
>   { message: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.,    domain:
>   global, reason: forbidden } ], status: PERMISSION_DENIED } }

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `getClient()` function does. But assuming it handles requesting the access token similar to the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/php), you will want to set the scope **BEFORE** it runs the logic to get the access token. So probably change the getClient() function to take a parameter for the scopes to request, and set the scopes in there before the access token request.